# Mouse cursor frequently disappears

Tags: macos, mojave, mouse, catalina

On macOS Mojave 10.14.5 through Catalina 10.15.2, my mouse pointer becomes invisible frustratingly often.

The only way to make it visible again is to enter Mission Control or to click on the middle part of the menu bar at the top of the screen, where there isn't a button.

Wiggling the cursor does not make it visible again, but the "enlarge cursor when wiggling" option is on.

Changing the cursor size does not prevent this problem.

Resetting NVRAM does not noticeably fix this problem.

I am using a MacBook pro with retina display mid-2015.

The problem happens on both trackpad and mouse

Comment: Does this happen with a mouse or trackpad or both? (You don't mention what kind of Mac you are using.)

Comment: Do you have any 3rd party software or driver (e.g. Logitech) installed which might interfere with the mouse? Or an application which might disable the mouse pointer from time to time? Can you create a new user on your Mac, log in there and check whether it happens for the new user as well?

Comment: I have the same problem with 10.13.5. I am using Karabiner-Elements. It isn't easy to investigate, even with a new user context because I don't have any idea what application or event might reproduce the problem.

Comment: @danielAzuelos do you think karabiner causes the problem?

Comment: I didn't start the investigation yet. Could you add the information requested in 1st comment by @IconDaemon?

Comment: @danielAzuelos I've only experienced the issue with 3rd party software so far (not Karabiner, but similar). So disabling it for a while to see whether the problem disappears might be a good approach here.

Comment: For me it happens on mouse and trackpad. It happens during videogames, like League of Legends, but also happens somewhat randomly. i can RELIABLY make it happen by hitting cmd tab a few times to bring up app switcher. not just hitting cmd tab, tab, i mean cmd tab, cmd tab tab, cmd tab. if you do it enough, eventually itll disappear. osx 10.14.6, mbp 15inch mid 2019. @IconDaemon

Comment: Does that info help you at all @dan ?

Comment: I also have this issue. Brand new laptop. :(

Answer (score 2):

I have this problem sometimes with 10.14.6.  I can fix it by moving the mouse to one of my hot corners (e.g. start screensaver) or by clicking on one of the top menu items.  Basically I move it all the way to an edge of the screen even though I can't see it, and then trigger a response.
It's still pretty aggravating, but at least I can get back on my way pretty fast.

Comment: Annoying when you don't have enough reputation to comment. Unfortunately this is not an answer. I already know some methods to show the cursor again, the question is asking how to stop it from disappearing in the first place.

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you use Karabiner Elements?

Comment: I am not using Karabiner Elements.  I am using multiple screens with sometimes heavy RAM/CPU usage.  (thankfully I can comment on my own post!)

Answer (score 0):

I found this helpful. (iMac 2015 MacOS 10.14.6)
https://osxdaily.com/2013/07/19/disappearing-mouse-cursor-mac-os-x/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  We're trying to find the best answers and those answers will provide info as to why they're the best. Explain why you think the link you provided will answer the question.  Answers should be self-contained so others can find them by using the search feature.  Links can change and become outdated so we prefer the answers to not just be a link.  See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have this same issue sometimes when I hover over the dock. I do not know the root cause unfortunately, but I can offer a slightly more permanent solution than clicking the menu bar. This fixes the problem for me for quite some time (months?), although it is possible for it to regress.

**Restart Finder**

1. Press <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Escape</kbd> to open *Force Quit Applications*.
2. Choose **Finder**.
3. Click **Relaunch**.
   [image]